# Fill object that has holes with text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, logo

I am trying to create a logo where a text is inside a shape that has holes, but I want it to be within the shape, including the eyes and teeth. The eyes and teeth are just filled white here and the client doesn't want any words missing.

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do so. Maybe I can space it in such a way?

Comment: Make the eyes and mouth only have a stroke and no fill? I am not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want new text that only fits inside the eyes and mouth that is different than the face text?

Comment: You want a **logo** with such small type? It'll never be readable.

Comment: Is that.. a robotnik face?

Answer (score 12):

If the shape you are trying to fill is a compound path, use the Knife Tool to make cuts in it so that it is no longer a compound path. Then you can use the Area Type tool by clicking on the path. Then copy and paste some text into it.

[image]

Comment: I was writing a much longer answer. :-) This is better. The problem for the OP is that the words are too long to fit in between the eyes and teeth. But this is a quick way to find out.

Comment: @Wolff - sure, but maybe adding spaces might help. Might not look great though.

Comment: Thank you so much! Cutting tool might work perfectly for what I am doing. I also remade the spaces and tried to make them wrap with no space and it kinda worked but I will try the cut method too, thank you <3